# docker compose in jenkins container

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose

I'm trying to run docker compose build commands inside my a Jenkins which is a docker container.

I did volume mapping to the docker.sock and also added the docker binary.

THe docker command works well, for example: `docker run hello-world works` well. But for some reason I get `docker: 'compose' is not a docker command.` even though the command works perfectly in the host machine.

This is my Dockerfile for building the Jenkins image:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins

EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 50000

ARG GROUP_ID

USER root

RUN jenkins-plugin-cli --plugins "blueocean docker-workflow"

RUN groupadd -g $GROUP_ID docker \
&& gpasswd -a jenkins docker

RUN newgrp docker

USER jenkins
```

This is the docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  jenkins-blueocean:
    build:
      context: .
      
    image: jenkins-blueocean

    container_name: jenkins-blueocean

    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "50000:50000"

    restart: "on-failure"

    volumes:
      - "jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
      - "/usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker"
      

volumes:
  jenkins_home:
```

And I run the command like this:

```
docker compose build --build-arg GROUP_ID=$(getent group docker | cut --delimiter ':' --fields 3)

docker compose up -d --no-build
```

Comment: Older version of docker had `docker-compose` and `docker` as two distinct binaries. `compose` as a sub command of `docker`was added in "later" revisions. What is your version of Docker? And do you have a `docker-compose` binary?

Comment: Docker version: 24.0.7, build afdd53b
I don't have a docker-compose binary, only docker binary

Comment: Those are still different plugins you have to install. How did you install docker on your Jenkins machine/runner?

Comment: I used the convenience script from the installation guide: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/

Comment: Ok. I used the command "docker info" and saw that the plugin was installed in the path: /usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose. So I added this in the volumes: "/usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose:/usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose". And now the "docker compose" command works inside the jenkins container

Comment: Thanks! I also wanted to know if this is the way it's usually done or is there a better approach